# Tic Tac Toe using C++ and multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Thanks everyone for your help, I'm new to programming and I'm not very skillful, so I appreciate your patience. I got it to work! There were several problems in the code, from the for loops used to check for "game over" and the counter used to set up the board. But the final code seems to be bug free. It prints out in the console a grid with labeled squares that allows two people to play together. Very happy right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool over = false;

void print_board(char board[3][3])
{
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[0][0]<<"  |  "<<board[0][1]<< "  |  "<<board[0][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<< "  |  "<<board[1][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<< "  |  "<<board[2][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
}

bool checkForCorrectMove (char board[3][3], int choice, bool player1Turn)
{
    int xCor;
    int yCor;
    xCor = ((choice + 2) / 3) - 1; 
    yCor = (choice - 1) % 3;
    if (((board[xCor][yCor]) != 'X') && ((board[xCor][yCor]) != 'O'))
    {
        if (player1Turn)
            board[xCor][yCor] = 'X';
        if (!player1Turn)
            board[xCor][yCor] = 'O';
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

bool checkRow(char board[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if ((board[i][0] == board[i][1]) && (board[i][1] == board[i][2]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool checkColumn (char board[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if ((board[0][i] == board[1][i]) && (board[1][i] == board[2][i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool checkForWin (char board[3][3])
{
    bool win = false;
    bool line_win = false;
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[2][2]))
    {
        win = true;
        return win;
    }
    if ((board[2][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[0][2]))
    {
        win = true;
        return win;
    }

    if (checkColumn(board) || checkRow (board))
    {
        win = true;
        return win;
    }
    return win;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!\n";
    int choice;
    int boardcounter = 1;
    bool isOkayToMove = true;
    bool player1Turn = true;
    char board[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = boardcounter + '0';
            boardcounter++;
        }
    }
    print_board(board);
    do {
        if (player1Turn)
        {
            cout <<"\n\nPlayer 1, please enter a number that corresponds to an open space: ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"\n\nPlayer 2, please enter a number that corresponds to an open space: ";
        }
        cin>>choice;
        isOkayToMove = checkForCorrectMove(board, choice, player1Turn);
        if (isOkayToMove)
        {
            over = checkForWin(board);
            print_board(board);
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"\n\nYou have attempted to move into a space that is already occupied, please try again.";
            print_board(board);
        }
    }
    while (over == false);
    cout <<"\n\nCongratulations!";
    player1Turn = !player1Turn;
    if (player1Turn)
        cout<<" Player 1 has won!";
    else
        cout<<" Player 2 has won!";
}
```

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe game in C++, but I'm struggling. I know this has been asked before, but it's hard to figure out what's wrong with my specific code (I'm learning C++), by looking at others' examples. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool over = false;

void print_board(char board[3][3])
{
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[0][0]<<"  |  "<<board[0][1]<< "  |  "<<board[0][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[1][0]<<"  |  "<<board[1][1]<< "  |  "<<board[1][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n  "<<board[2][0]<<"  |  "<<board[2][1]<< "  |  "<<board[2][2];
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
}

bool checkForCorrectMove (char board[][3], int choice, bool player1Turn)
{
    int xCor;
    int yCor;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: xCor = 0, yCor = 0;
        case 2: xCor = 0, yCor = 1;
        case 3: xCor = 0, yCor = 2;
        case 4: xCor = 1, yCor = 0;
        case 5: xCor = 1, yCor = 1;
        case 6: xCor = 1, yCor = 2;
        case 7: xCor = 2, yCor = 0;
        case 8: xCor = 2, yCor = 1;
        case 9: xCor = 2, yCor = 2;
    }
    if (((board[xCor][yCor]) != 'X') && ((board[xCor][yCor]) != 'O'))
    {
        if (player1Turn)
            board[xCor][yCor] = 'X';
        if (!player1Turn)
            board[xCor][yCor] = 'O';
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

bool checkForWin (char board[][3])
{
    bool win = false;
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[2][2]))
    {
        win = true;
    }
    else if ((board[2][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[0][2]))
    {
        win = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (board[i][j] != board [i][0]);
            win = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (board[i][j] != board [0][j]);
            win = false;
        }
    }
    return win;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!\n";
    int choice;
    int boardcounter = 1;
    bool isOkayToMove = true;
    bool player1Turn = true;
    char board[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = (char) boardcounter;
            boardcounter++;
        }
    }
    print_board(board);
    do {
        if (player1Turn)
        {
            cout <<"\n\nPlayer 1, please enter a number that corresponds to an open space: ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"\n\nPlayer 2, please enter a number that corresponds to an open space: ";
        }
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice);
        isOkayToMove = checkForCorrectMove(board, choice, player1Turn);
        if (isOkayToMove)
        {
            print_board(board);
            over = checkForWin(board);
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"\n\nYou have attempted to move into a space that is already occupied, please try again.";
            print_board(board);
        }
    }
    while (over == false);
    cout <<"\n\nCongratulations!";
    if (player1Turn)
        cout<<" Player 1 has won!";
    else
        cout<<" Player 2 has won!";
}
```

Comment: "I'm struggling" is an unsuitable problem description. I can tell you that your `switch` is missing `break`s on each `case` (which themselves have some questionable assignment statements — where did you hear that C++ separates statements with commas?) but, beyond that, you're going to need to provide an MCVE to explain what the actual problem is...

Comment: Well what's wrong with it? If it doesn't compile, you should post the error message. If it doesn't run as expected, explain what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: @JonathanMa - Your `switch` can be condensed to `xCor = ((choice + 2) / 3) - 1; yCor = choice % 3;`

Comment: It compiles - but for now, the problem lies with the print_board function and how I initialized the board. It prints two rows of giberrish characters and an empty third row.

Comment: You could use `for` statements to print the board.  Looping constructs are very helpful with arrays (including 2 dimensional arrays).

Comment: @owacoder: Because that's really readable and easily maintainable.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what printable character you expected `(char)1` to be.

Comment: The switch change and the (char) 1 problem were helpful. I just changed it to int + '0' which made the board print correctly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - It is "easily maintainable" compared to a switch with a repetitive pattern.

Comment: sorry for the unhelpful post, this isn't hw (im a teacher picking up programming as a hobby) but i was so lost that i didn't know which part of the program was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an issue I found:

```
    int boardcounter = 1;
//...
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = (char) boardcounter;
            boardcounter++;
        }
```

The issue is that the cast `(char)` does not convert the `int` variable into a *textual* representation.  The cast actually converts the integer to smaller sized integer variable.

There are many ways to convert a number to a character, such as `snprintf`, `tostring`, and `ostringstream`.

Since you have a limited range, i.e. digits 0 - 9, you may be able to get away with:

```
board[row][column] = '0' + boardcounter;
```

I suggest you review your code and find other places where an integer is being converted to `char` and change it accordingly.

BTW, most Tic-Tac-Toe games use ' ', 'X' and 'O' as values.

Comment: thanks for the response, that was a big problem. but I didn't use spaces because numbers give users the ability to input labels to change the board.